# Magento 2.1 extension how to load everywhere?

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, extensions

I created an extension in my local environment.
So far I'm able to set some parameters from the admin

I also created a frontend route, so I can access a custom page at

`http://localhost/magento/myextension/index/index`

And I have the associated controller

`/app/code/Tony/myExtension/Controller/Index/Index.php`

Now I'd need to

**1. Add options to load my extension on certain page types (eg. Cart, Home, Product) in system.xml**

I already created

`app/code/Tony/myExtension/etc/adminhtml/system.xml`

**2. Read this options from my Helper.**

I have created my Helper here

`app/code/Tony/myExtension/Helper/Data.php`

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access your module class's functions in any class by Dependency injection.

ex: if you want to use your Module Helper class:
use this code in any class:

```
protected $_dataHelper;

public function __construct(\app\code\Tony\myExtension\Helper\Data $dataHelper)
{$this->_dataHelper = $dataHelper;}
```

then you can call any function of this data helper class anywhere in this class by:

```
$this->_dataHelper->functionName();
```

Comment: awesome, I figured this out yesterday :)
I also learnt that sometimes you have to override the parent constructor...
I noticed that you can create view/frontend/layout/XML and depending on the name, it will be loaded somewhere in the frontend. Is there a list of possible names for these XML files??

Comment: @macom89 yes these layout XML files are loaded basis on their name. for example , if you look at this file:
magento_root/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml
this layout will be load at 
site.url/customer/account/create request.
So the layout file's name would be "module's-route-name_controller_action.xml"